# Object into Array conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have this state Object in a class:

```
state = {
    ingredients: {
        salad: 1,
        bacon: 5, 
        cheese: 2, 
        meat: 2
    }
}
```

and want to convert it into an array that gets also the value number, like this:

```
const burger = (props) => {
const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
    .map(igKey => {
        return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_,i)=>{
           return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey}/>
        });
    });

    console.log(transformedIngredients)
    return(
        <div className={classes.Burger}> 
        <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
        <BurgerIngredient type="cheese" />
        <BurgerIngredient type="meat" />
        <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default burger;
```

I succeeded in doing it following a tutorial and to be honest I do not completely understand what is happening here. especially this part:

```
return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_,i)=>{
       return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey}/>
    });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen the three dots before: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: yes the spread operator! :)

Comment: I just wasn't clear whjich bit of the expression was tripping you up - but the answer you got has walked through it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`igKey` is one of the keys of your ingredients, `bacon` for example. Now that is looked up in the ingredients with

```
 props.ingredients[igKey]
```

which then results in the amount, `5` in this case. Now that is used to build up an array with that length:

```
 Array(5) // { length: 5 }
```

Now that array is a sparse array, it has nothing in it. To be able to iterate over it with `map`, it has to be filled with not defined values, therefore that sparse array is spread into a new array, which turns it into a filled array:

```
 [...Array(5)] // { length: 5, 0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: ... }
```

Now that empty array with 5 entries will be mapped to an array with 5 Burger ingredients.

---

By the way more elegant IMO:

```
 Array.from(
   { length: props.infredients[igKey] },
   (_, i) => <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey}/>
 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you put it in simple but clear words! thanks :)

Comment: @michael glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
props.ingredients[igKey]
```

returns a number, 5 for example for bacon.

```
[...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])]
```

returns an array of n elements. Those elements are undefined as you haven't filled them yet.

A solution would be:

```
[...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].fill(igKey)
```

Or simply:

```
Array(state.ingredients[igKey]).fill(igKey)
```

That results in:

```
["salad", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "cheese", "cheese", "meat", "meat"]
```